# Sharepoint online copy file script

Tags: powershell, sharepoint-online, csom

I am having trouble copying a file within a sharepoint online list using powershell. Error I am getting is
Exception calling "ExecuteQuery" with "0" argument(s): "Server relative urls must start with SPWeb.ServerRelativeUrl"

The path is correct as i can combine context.url with the path variables and access the file using that path. I used similar paths except with getfolderbyrelativeurl to set permissions on folders with no issues (same list).

Here is the code.

```
$Context = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($SiteUrl)
$SourceFile =$context.Web.GetFileByServerRelativeUrl("/$ListName/$sa_man_checklist")
$Context.Load($SourceFile)
$Context.ExecuteQuery()
```

I am very new sharepoint online and any help is much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Found the cause, not sure how anything before this worked. Server relative url should have started after host name rather than what i specified in context. Odd thing is when i called folder by server relative path taking url specified in context it still works just fine but when i try to call a file using that same method it breaks...